# Write string to output stream

Tags: java, io, stream, outputstream

I have several output listeners that are implementing `OutputStream`.
It can be either a `PrintStream` writing to stdout or to a File, or it can be writing to memory or any other output destination; therefore, I specified `OutputStream` as (an) argument in the method.

Now, I have received the `String`. What is the best way to write to streams here?

Should I just use `Writer.write(message.getBytes())`? I can give it bytes, but if the destination stream is a character stream then will it convert automatically?

Do I need to use some bridge streams here instead?

Comment: I am not sure but this sounds like you are trying to reinvent the wheel here, have you looked through the Java Base API, as well as Commons IO API?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Streams (`InputStream` and `OutputStream`) transfer *binary* data. If you want to write a string to a stream, you must first convert it to bytes, or in other words *encode* it. You can do that manually (as you suggest) using the `String.getBytes(Charset)` method, but you should avoid the `String.getBytes()` method, because that uses the default encoding of the JVM, which can't be reliably predicted in a portable way.

The usual way to write character data to a stream, though, is to wrap the stream in a [`Writer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html), (often a [`PrintWriter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html)), that does the conversion for you when you call its [`write(String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write(java.lang.String)) (or [`print(String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#print(java.lang.String))) method. The corresponding wrapper for InputStreams is a [Reader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html).

`PrintStream` is a special `OutputStream` implementation in the sense that it also contain methods that automatically encode strings (it uses a writer internally). But it is still a stream. You can safely wrap your stream with a writer no matter if it is a `PrintStream` or some other stream implementation. There is no danger of double encoding.

Example of PrintWriter with OutputStream:

```
try (PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("output-text.txt", true))) {
    p.println("Hello");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: So using `PrintWriter` is just like using `String.getBytes()`. It uses whatever random encoding that happens to be the default of the JVM. So it only works if you're lucky.

Comment: the code snippet should really be using a constructor that also takes a `Charset` param, especially given the first paragraph of the answer...

Answer (score 126):

OutputStream writes bytes, String provides chars. You need to define Charset to encode string to byte[]:

```
outputStream.write(string.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

Change `UTF-8` to a charset of your choice.

Comment: Append with the following line. `ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();`

Comment: `.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` is a little bit cleaner

Answer (score 35):

You can create a PrintStream wrapping around your OutputStream and then just call it's print(String):

```
final OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/out");
final PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(os);
printStream.print("String");
printStream.close();
```

Comment: What character set is PrintStream using to convert to bytes?

Answer (score 30):

[By design](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) it is to be done this way:

```
OutputStream out = ...;
try (Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8")) {
    w.write("Hello, World!");
} // or w.close(); //close will auto-flush
```

Comment: Note that `w.close()` will close `out` as well.

Comment: I prefer this answer because it provides an explicit encoding specification! And I recommend using the existing predefined encodings, like StandardCharsets.UTF_8 instead of String literals ("UTF-8").

Answer (score 13):

Wrap your OutputStream with a [PrintWriter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) and use the print methods on that class.  They take in a String and do the work for you.

Answer (score 9):

You may use [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/):

```
try (OutputStream outputStream = ...) {
    IOUtils.write("data", outputStream, "UTF-8");
}
```

- [IOUtils.write(String data, OutputStream output, String encoding)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#write(java.lang.String,%20java.io.OutputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset))

Comment: `IOUtils.write(String data, OutputStream output, Charset encoding)` is implemented as `output.write(data.getBytes(Charsets.toCharset(encoding)))`, so it may if an encoded string can't fit in a byte array